# Лямбда выражения

Tags: java, lambda

Хочу использовать лямбда-выражения, по этим двум статьями взял примеры:

- [Статья 1](http://habrahabr.ru/post/224593/)
- [Статья 2](http://habrahabr.ru/post/216431/)

Но в итоге не получается.
Использую java 8, android studio 1.

Что еще ему надо, или чего я не понимаю?

[image]

Comment: несомненно, скриншот с красной волнистой линией - это очень информативное описание вашей ошибки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установите java 8, в структуре проекта укажите где лежит ваш jdk 1.8.
После в gradle project добавьте следующее:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        ...............................................
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.0'
    }
}
```

После в gradle app добавьте следующее:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    ..............................................

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

К сожалению, пока что при написании приложений под андроид 1.8 недоступен, поэтому лямбды и прочие фишки новой jdk использовать не получится.

Comment: а есть ли планы у них какие нибудь на это

Comment: Вот этого я не знаю

Comment: @eldqs, планы, конечно же есть. Наверняка уже идут работы по адаптации восьмой JDK к Android разработке, ибо новая JDK несет в себе не только фичи, но и патчи.

Answer (score 2):

Если хотите использовать лямбда в Android Studio, попробуйте [gradle-retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda). Он интегрирует в gradle инструмент, который конвертирует Java 8 bytecode в Java 6/7.